# Importrange + Query + Matches + Regexp

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to filter out data from a different sheet with a specific account number. However the code below doesn't give out any results

```
=query(importrange(Setup!B1,"Sheet1!A2:F"),"Select * where Col4 matches '\d\d-\d\d\d\d-[14-7]\d\d\d'",1)
```

This is supposed to filter out all accounts where the 1st digit in the 3rd group of numbers is either 1,4,5,6 or 7. The width of the account numbers are all the same following the format xx-xxxx-xxxx.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your match criteria:

`\d{2}-\d{4}-[14-7]{3}\d`

Also, while I can't see your data, make sure you actually have a header in the first row of your IMPORTRANGE results (which you've requested with the `1` at the end of the `QUERY`). If you don't actually have headers, the `1` will leave you with one more result than you want; if that is the case, just remove the `,1` from the end of the `QUERY`.

If this doesn't produce the results you want, it may be due to mixed data types in your raw data that are being filtered out by the `QUERY`. In that case, you can try using `FILTER` and `REGEXMATCH` instead:

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE(Setup!B1,"Sheet1!A2:F"),REGEXMATCH(IMPORTRANGE(Setup!B1,"Sheet1!D2:D"),"\d{2}-\d{4}-[14-7]{3}\d")))`

It is always hard to write complex formulas sight unseen. If none of these solutions (which work in my local sheet) produce the results you expect, I encourage you to share a link to both of your sheets. The raw data sheet being called by `IMPORTRANGE` can be "View Only"; but you'll want to set the Share permission on the second sheet (the one with the `IMPORTRANGE` formula itself) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that those here can access it to test.